# uniform convergence to zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the sequence of functions $\{y_{m}(x)\}$ on $[a,b]$. Assume that $|y_{m}(x)|\leq M_{m}$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ and all $m\in Z^{+}$ .  Suppose $\Sigma_{m=1}^{+\infty}M_{m}<+\infty$. Is it possible to say $y_{m}(x)$ uniformly converges to zero on $[a,b]$? (The sequence $\{M_{m}\}$ is a numeric sequence in $R$)

Comment: Well,  $(M_m)$ must converge to $0$...

Comment: I see. I know that $y_{m}(x)$ converges to zero pointwisely on $[a,b]$. Can we say it also converges uniformly?

Comment: Yes. Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $N$ with $M_m<\epsilon$ for all $m\ge N$. Then for all $m\ge N$ and all $x\in[a,b]$, you have $|y_m(x)|\le M_m<\epsilon$. (In fact, the series $\sum y_m(x)$ converges uniformly. Google "Weierstrass M-Test".)

Comment: @T.A.Ben: You are asking if the sequence $(y_{m})$ converges uniformly, right? It follows directly from $M_{m} \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum_{m}M_{m}$ converges, then $M_{m} \to 0$ by an elementary result in analysis. If $|y_{m}(x)| \leq M_{m}$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and all $m \geq 1$, then $|y_{m}| \to 0$ uniformly on $[a,b]$, so $y_{m} \to 0$ uniformly on $[a,b]$.